# Query tune/rewrite, need suggestion on using join instead of in and on corrections if and where needed

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Could someone suggest if this query needs any changes, can be improved/rewritten to perform better

```
select i.artificial_document_type, 
i.PARENT_ID, 
 i.amount, 
 i.drn, 
 i.capture_drn, 
 i.sequence_number, 
 i.source, 
  i.proof_classification, 
 i.posting_date, 
 i.item_type, 
 i.id, 
 j.CAPTURE_STATION_ID from Item i, 
CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION j  where i.CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION_ID  =  j.ID and 
j.ID in (select j.ID from CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION j where CAPTURE_STATION_ID like ('RDB'))  
and i.AMOUNT  > '0'  and i.ARTIFICIAL_DOCUMENT_TYPE  > '0';
```

Comment: It won't help performance, but it will help readability if you use explicit `join` syntax (it is ANSI standard for almost 30 years).

Comment: Unrelated, but, `like ('RDB')` can be simplified to `= 'RDB'`

Comment: `i.AMOUNT  > '0'` is amount really a text datatype?

Comment: Don't compare numbers with strings. `'0'` is a string, `0` is a number. Maybe the use of incorrect literals prevents index usage. Try `i.amount > 0 and i.ARTIFICIAL_DOCUMENT_TYPE  > 0` and see if that changes anything

Comment: As others have pointed out, there are a few ways your code logic might be improved. But we cannot offer tuning advice without a lot more details regarding table structure, indexing, data volume and skew, database version, performance goals and much else besides. Otherwise we're just guessing, and that's a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an inner join for avoid IN clause and use numeric value for comparision

```
select i.artificial_document_type, 
 i.PARENT_ID, 
 i.amount, 
 i.drn, 
 i.capture_drn, 
 i.sequence_number, 
 i.source, 
 i.proof_classification, 
 i.posting_date, 
 i.item_type, 
 i.id, 
 j.CAPTURE_STATION_ID 
 from Item i
 INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION j  ON  i.CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION_ID  =  j.ID 
 INNER JOIN (
      select j.ID 
      from CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION j 
      where CAPTURE_STATION_ID like ('RDB')
 ) t on t.id = j.id 
where i.AMOUNT  > 0  
and i.ARTIFICIAL_DOCUMENT_TYPE  > 0;
```

Be sure you have al least proper index on  table  Item column CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION_ID 
  and eventaally a composite index on column  ( USTOMER_TRANSACTION_ID , AMOUNT, ARTIFICIAL_DOCUMENT_TYPE)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if kiran was simply looking for an outer join with `CAPTURE_STATION_ID like ('RDB')` being part of the join condition (removing the sub-query alltogether) - but this is hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

Two cases are possible and performance wise first case is useful to you.

Case 1

```
    select i.artificial_document_type, 
     i.PARENT_ID, 
     i.amount, 
     i.drn, 
     i.capture_drn, 
     i.sequence_number, 
     i.source, 
     i.proof_classification, 
     i.posting_date, 
     i.item_type, 
     i.id, 
     j.CAPTURE_STATION_ID 
     from Item i
     INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION j  ON  i.CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION_ID  =  j.ID 
     AND j.CAPTURE_STATION_ID like ('RDB')
     and i.AMOUNT  > '0'  and i.ARTIFICIAL_DOCUMENT_TYPE  > '0';
```

Case 2

```
    select i.artificial_document_type, 
     i.PARENT_ID, 
     i.amount, 
     i.drn, 
     i.capture_drn, 
     i.sequence_number, 
     i.source, 
     i.proof_classification, 
     i.posting_date, 
     i.item_type, 
     i.id, 
     j.CAPTURE_STATION_ID 
     from Item i
     INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION j  ON  i.CUSTOMER_TRANSACTION_ID  =  j.ID 
     AND j.CAPTURE_STATION_ID like ('RDB')
     WHERE i.AMOUNT  > '0'  and i.ARTIFICIAL_DOCUMENT_TYPE  > '0';
```

Comment: Neither of them will make any difference in performance

Comment: When you will put some condition in where then its filter out all records after join but you want to add like in left join or etc then it would be the filter on joining records and this is useful.